# Use latexdiff efficiency to build point-by-point response to reviewers

Tags: latexdiff, quotation

I'm trying to gain in efficiency in building a point-by-point response to reviewers of my scientific papers.
I feel `latexdiff`very efficient to track changes.
Similarly, I find the way to quote what you add to the revised version of the manuscript very efficient as you don't have to copy and paste (and to modify again and again after multiples corrections) (see Elizabeth Hobson's elegant solution https://sites.google.com/site/hobsonresearch/r-resources/latex-revision-hacks).

But I struggle to combine these solutions. Is there any way to tag latexdiff output to ref it in the response?
I gave a thought on using `grep` but with no label, no possible reference...

**Edit:**
What I've been able to figure out is not elegant but does the work:

1. write my edits and use the `qting` package to include them in the point-by-point response to the reviewers. This would create a *revised_with_quotes tex file*.
2. use `sed` to remove the `q`quote command (sed 's/\q{([^}\{]*)}{([^}\{]*)}/\2/g' revised_with_quotes.tex > revised_without_quotes.tex)
3. use `latexdiff` between the original file and the revised_wihtout_quotes.tex file.

I guess there may be more elegant and efficient solution bu I was not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--append-textcmd=defquotedtext` option. I tested that with Elisabeth Hobson's text, and it worked for a change in one of the quotes.
A side-effect of that solution is that the markup will be visible in the text quotation, too, which might or might not be what you want (I probably would not want that to keep the response clean).  You can probably solve that by redefining \DIFadd and \DIFdel commands before the 'response' section of your .tex file.

PS: The sed command might fail if the argument of \defquotedtext contains nested opening { and closing } parentheses. Have a look at option `-m/--markup` of `latexrevise` (distributed with `latexdiff` but largely unknown) should achieve this in a more robust way.

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of Elisabeth Hobson's post, by the way. I always thought of writing responses in this way, but was always to lazy to implement something myself.

Comment: actually the following perl command will do the job instead of using sed, that cannot deal with nested parentheses : perl -pe 's/\\q\{.*} ( \{ ( (?: [^}{]+ | (?1))*+ ) \} )/$2/gx' file.tex (from @ilkkachu https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/666222/isolate-content-of-curly-brackets-which-can-contain-nested-curly-brackets)